# return oracle service bus error code

Tags: oracle, service, osb, bus

I'm creating a proxy in Oracle Service Bus 11G for a webservice. After receiving the request and when the response is 200, everything is ok, the OSB return the same 200 code.

Now, in my WebService I raise error 400, 406, 403, etc. depending of some logic processing but the OSB always raise error 500.

There's a way to make OSB forward the plain answer including the error code?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add a fault handler to the business service

Extract variables from `data($fault//*:http-response-code)` and `data($fault//*:reason)` (or something similar

Insert:

`<http:http-response-code>$response_code_variable</http:http-response-code>`
 as last child of
 `./ctx:transport/ctx:response`
In Variable – `$inbound`

Insert:

`<tp:response-message>$response_reason_variable</tp:response-message>`
after
`./ctx:transport/ctx:response/ctx:response-code`
In Variable – `$inbound`